# Error in maxent log "occurrence point missing some environmental data...skipping sample"

Tags: arcgis-pro, maxent, nlcd

I am very new to Maxent.

I did a test run for a species distribution model in the program and I received many errors of the same issue that are recorded in the .log file for the run. Here is an example of the message (this is just one of like 30-ish of the same error message):

Warning: Sample at -89.285172, 43.128795 in puberulenta_training.csv is missing some environmental data (e.g. elevation)
Warning: Skipping sample at -89.285172, 43.128795

I went into ArcGIS Pro to troubleshoot my layers. I know the common issue for this error is that my species occurrence data falls outside of my environmental data layers/study area but this was not the issue. I double checked each layer against the occurrence data and all of it falls within all environmental layers. But, I found this with my impervious surface data.

[image]

You can see the purple points (my occurrence data) do not always fall within the pixels of the impervious surface data.

Could this be what is causing the issue?

If so, how could I fix this?

Could I make the layer more continuous looking in ArcGIS Pro?

Or, could I just ignore this since there is literally no data?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.